# Dataframe column names np array has \n after one of the column names

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am trying to sum the values of select columns from a list of columns and store it in a new column. However, I keep getting

> raise KeyError('%s not in index' % objarr[mask])
>
> KeyError: "['a' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'e'\n 'f'] not in index"

This is the piece of code where I am trying to achieve this :

```
cols = df.columns.values
colIndex = np.argwhere('Person')
selectCols = np.delete(cols, colIndex)
df['total counts'] = df[selectCols].sum(axis=1)
```

First I'm not sure how the `\n` is present after column `e` and secondly I don't know what's causing this KeyError. Please help!

Comment: don you want `df['total counts'] = df[df.columns.difference(['Person'])].sum(axis=1)`?

Comment: Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve]. Also, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [290]: np.argwhere('Person')                                                                
Out[290]: array([], shape=(1, 0), dtype=int64)
```

It doesn't make sense to use that in `np.delete`.

Show `cols`

===

```
In [301]: cols = np.array(['Person', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'])                            
In [302]: idx = np.argwhere('Person')                                                          
In [303]: idx                                                                                  
Out[303]: array([], shape=(1, 0), dtype=int64)
In [304]: np.delete(cols, idx)                                                                 
Out[304]: array(['Person', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], dtype='<U6')
```

alternatively we can find where `cols` is equal to 'Person':

```
In [305]: idx = np.argwhere(cols=='Person')                                                    
In [306]: idx                                                                                  
Out[306]: array([[0]])
In [307]: np.delete(cols, idx)                                                                 
Out[307]: array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], dtype='<U6')
```

or working with a list version of `cols`:

```
In [313]: alist = cols.tolist()                                                                                      
In [314]: alist                                                                                                      
Out[314]: ['Person', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
In [315]: alist.remove('Person')                                                                                     
In [316]: alist                                                                                                      
Out[316]: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

===

replicating more of your case:

```
In [317]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.ones((2,4),int), columns=['a','b','c','d'])                                           
In [318]: df                                                                                                         
Out[318]: 
   a  b  c  d
0  1  1  1  1
1  1  1  1  1
In [319]: cols = df.columns.values                                                                                   
In [320]: cols                                                                                                       
Out[320]: array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], dtype=object)
In [322]: np.argwhere(cols=='a')                                                                                     
Out[322]: array([[0]])
In [323]: np.delete(cols, _)                                                                                         
Out[323]: array(['b', 'c', 'd'], dtype=object)
In [324]: df[_]                                                                                                      
Out[324]: 
   b  c  d
0  1  1  1
1  1  1  1
In [326]: df[_323].sum(axis=1)                                                                                       
Out[326]: 
0    3
1    3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: This is the output for `print(cols)` - `['Person' 'a' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'e'                                                         
 'f']`. Cmd changes the line after `e` which I can't get the comment box to do here.

Comment: Getting `Person` removed is not the issue. I've already done that. As you can see in the error, `Person` is already removed from the list.

Comment: The '\n' suggests that you are passing a print string of an array, not the actual array at the column selector.  Something is happening your code (or session) that you aren't showing.  If it is repeatable, show the `cols` after the delete.